# Creating a SUBSTR in SQL Plus

Tags: sql, oracle

This is the homework question I am having issues with:

Using the BOOKS table and the SUBSTR function, create a query that will return a list of book ISBN codes and the book title for all the computer books. Format the ISBN code to display as 9-999-99999-9 (e.g., 1059831198 would display as 1-059-83119-8)

My code is below as to what I have so far:

```
SELECT ISBN, Title,Category
SUBSTR(ISBN,1,3,4,1 )
FROM BOOKS;
WHERE Category = 'Computer';
```

The error I got was:
    ERROR at line 2:
    ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

After playing around with it for a bit I realized that I'm not allowed to have that many numbers in my `SUBSTR` to split up the ISBN but I've looked up my in my textbook and online and I cannot figure out how to d do my `SUBSTR` with that many dashes between all those numbers.

Also I tried doing the equation with just the two numbers and it worked but my WHERE clause is giving me issues and I don't know why either even though I researched the error , I'm not understanding. The course I am in is an entry course to SQL*Plus so it's very basic things I am doing but just have never done in my life so any input on what I'm doing wrong which I kind of know already that I'm not allowed to put that many numbers it so I guess if someone could point me in the right direction on how I could go about completing this substring.

Comment: what do you think `SUBSTR(ISBN,1,3,4,1 )` should return? where did you find such function at all?

Comment: also - don't forget to remove `;` after `books`, before `where`

Comment: The `SUBSTR()` function only takes 3 arguments, the source string, the start, and the length. You'll need more than one call to `SUBSTR()` to get the ISBN in the required format. You'll also need to use Oracle's concatenation operator `||`

Comment: The reported error stems from a missing comma between `Category`and your `SUBSTR` call ( the latter being malformed as other commenters noted).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to build up the string section by section, e.g.

`SUBSTR(ISBN,1,1) || '-' || SUBSTR(ISBN,2,3 ) || '-'` etc

Comment: Thanks! This made sense now that I see it! Thanks for all your help! I'm sure I'll have some more errors coming up as I am new at this and seem to have issues with all my questions but your help was greatly appreciated!.

Comment: So I've done it your way which was beyond helpful but I'm still getting the below error and I've looked up the error and still don't understand where my syntax is wrong?                                                                                SELECT ISBN,Title,Category
SUBSTR(ISBN, 1,1) || '-' ||
SUBSTR(ISBN, 3,3) || '_' ||
SUBSTR(ISBN, 5,5) || '_' ||
SUBSTR(ISBN, 10,1)|| '-' ||
FROM BOOKS
WHERE Cateory = 'Computer';
SUBSTR(ISBN, 1,1) || '-' ||
      *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Comment: There is no comma between Category and SUBSTR.  Also the SUBSTR line ends with a string concatenation character '||' which is invalid.  The concatenation character must have a string either side to concatenate (or join together)

Comment: I'm not sure how I would go about putting a string there to fix the issue. I'm not quite sure I understand(Again this is an entry class).  I took away the very last concatenation that fixed the error but now it's not selecting any rows @karl

Comment: Make sure it doesn't end with `||`. Also you spelled "Category" wrong near the end.

Answer (score 0):

The template for your solution could be:

```
SELECT Title
       -- reformatted isbn deliberately omitted - replace this line with your own work
  FROM BOOKS
 WHERE Category = 'Computer'
     ;
```

Note:
Consider this answer to be a comment that wishes to benefit from advanced formatting options ...

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out the answer to my own questions. The code is below:

```
SELECT Title,Category,
SUBSTR(ISBN, 1,1) || '-' || 
SUBSTR(ISBN, 3,3) || '-' || 
SUBSTR(ISBN, 5,5) || '-' || 
SUBSTR(ISBN, 10,1)
FROM BOOKS
WHERE Category = 'COMPUTER';
```

Thank you all for your helpful comments, it's greatly appreciated and helped me ultimately figure out my problem :)

Comment: Hi Nicolle  Are you sure about the numbers in your SUBSTR functions?  the first digit is the start position.  From you description of the problem I would expect to see these being 1,2,5,11.  I think your second digit looks correct.

Comment: I tested it out already in SQL*Plus and it came out in the correct format so it's working for me :)